# How to toggle certain comments in multiple files in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, comments, toggle, coderush

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 Website with multiple files(controllers) that have actions which accept [RequireHttps]. When I am working locally I want to be able to comment out all of these via a toggle/shortcut. I own CodeRush with Visual Studios 2010. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a project-wide search and replace of `[RequireHttps]` to `/*[RequireHttps]*/` or vice versa. You can record these as macros in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. However, this task requires creation of a [new CodeRush plug-in](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=KA18586).